# Get rectangle that was drawn earlier with Rectangle() function

Tags: c++, winapi

So I created a rectangle with Rectangle() function. When you are creating buttons, textboxes, you give them a certain number to access it later. Can I do the same with painted things?

P.S.: I need to create a rectangle and move it to another location

```
void SpawnRectangle(HDC hdc, int size, int amount)
{
    int Offset = size / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
    {
        int LocationX = rand() % 1300 + 50;
        int LocationY = rand() % 600 + 50;
        Rectangle(hdc, LocationX - Offset, LocationY - Offset, LocationX + Offset, LocationY + Offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep track of `LocationX`, `LocationY` and `Offset`. That's all you get, and all you need.

Comment: No, you can't. Basically things you paint yourself result simply in pixels on the screen. Nobody keeps track of them for you. OTOH a button or a textbox are complex objects handled by the operating system for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Rectangle` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rectangle) draws a rectangle on the screen.  It does not create a struct or class that defines the rectangle; it is literally the command to draw.

If you want to define a rectangle that you can use in other methods, [FillRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect), [FrameRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-framerect), etc., then you want the [RECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)) struct.  This is a structure that you can create and store for later use, modify, and pass into other drawing methods.